# iFrame issues within thin Joomla3 articles

Tags: php, html, iframe, cookies, joomla

I currently have a joomla3 website up and running which uses iframes within each Article page instead of using the option of the default HTML editor within joomla.

However some users are reporting blank pages hence they don't see the iframe content.

Could this be a javascript side issue or something to do with a popup blocker within the browser?

When the joomla portal is accessed using an ipad browser there are no issues and i am able to view all content.

Also the some of the iframes do use cookies, I'm not sure if this will have any effects on it?

Kind regards.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site and ask the clients that are having problems what browser they're using?

Comment: The users experiencing the issue are saying that they have tried all browsers. Could there be a similar alternative to using iframes? Or could there be a blocked placed by popup blockers or firewalls or maybe due to the use of cookies.